# Unable to Connect to SFTP with Public Key

Tags: windows, ssh, sftp, copssh

We use Copssh and we are having an issue getting Public Keys to properly work when connecting our SFTP. I've looked up as much as I could related to permissions, steps, etc. but I get a "Server refused our key" message.

What I did was created a key pair within Copssh, imported the private key into Puttygen, made sure the key was in the .ssh\authorized_keys file, and attmepted to connect in Filezilla and WinSCP. I also made sure to add +ssh-rsa to PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes but still get the same message. I also confirmed I see this setting in my sshd_config file but when connecting, these 2 lines appear in the server's logs:

```
2022.07.13 10:41:32 -  Failed publickey for devjoesftp2 from 10.81.70.3 port 64080 ssh2: RSA SHA256:GYnkAY7gsrTwT69r6XdEwVXOYb9F8KnguCGsX1/bMS0
2022.07.13 10:41:32 -  debug3: mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication test: RSA key is not allowed
```

My Filezilla sees this:

```
Trace:  Connecting to 10.81.64.205 port 22
Trace:  We claim version: SSH-2.0-FileZilla_3.60.1
Trace:  Connected to 10.81.64.205
Trace:  Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.0
Trace:  Using SSH protocol version 2
Trace:  Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256 (unaccelerated)
Trace:  Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/rsa-sha2-512/rsa-sha2-256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
Trace:  Host key fingerprint is:
Trace:  ssh-ed25519 255 SHA256:u4M+vpXf76UpFltUCPRDuv4dyiOmCa+/hxvEBwTnW4Y
Trace:  Initialised AES-256 GCM outbound encryption
Trace:  Initialised AES256 GCM outbound MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:  Initialised AES-256 GCM inbound encryption
Trace:  Initialised AES256 GCM inbound MAC algorithm (in ETM mode) (required by cipher)
Trace:  Successfully loaded 1 key pair from file
Status: Using username "devjoesftp". 
Trace:  Offered public key from "C:\Temp\SFTPTesting\devjoesftp1.ppk"
Status: Server refused our key 
Trace:  Server refused our key
Trace:  Attempting keyboard-interactive authentication
Trace:  Server refused keyboard-interactive authentication
Command:    Pass: 
Trace:  Sent password
Trace:  Password authentication failed
Status: Access denied 
Error:  Authentication failed.
Trace:  CControlSocket::DoClose(1030)
Trace:  CControlSocket::ResetOperation(1094)
Trace:  CSftpConnectOpData::Reset(1094) in state 3
Error:  Critical error: Could not connect to server
Trace:  CFileZillaEnginePrivate::ResetOperation(1094)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated on this as I have been stumped on this for days and know I'm missing something as when using Copssh's labs, I cannot reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

the reason is in the two lines you pasted from the server logs:

```
[...] RSA key is not allowed
```

Something in your server config is not allowing RSA keys.  I can understand dis-allowing DSA keys, but RSA is still considered secure enough.

You can either try to fix the server config, or you could create an ECDSA or other eliptic curve key, assuming the server allows those.

Comment: I agree. I am unsure what could be blocking RSA key from being allowed. I also tried to do a ECDSA key and got a similar message. Unsure why.  ----

mm_answer_keyallowed: publickey authentication test: ED25519 key is not allowed. ----

I'd like to fix my server config but need some help into what exactly I should be looking for as my previous research and troubleshooting has not worked.

Comment: I just realized that my message of: "RSA key is not allowed" is different than the lab I test in before adding +ssh-rsa to the AcceptedPubKeyTypes.

The lab shows as: userauth_pubkey: signature algorithm ssh-rsa not in PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms 

Makes me think either something is blocking before Copssh or it's something else possibly.

Answer (score 0):

This message was corrected after adding the SFTP user as an administrator on the server (strange, couldn't isolate that once this was discovered as to why this was needed). After that I got the error of incorrect ownership, etc. which was handled by modifying the home directory's permissions (removing all groups, etc. from home directory).

Answer (score 0):

I just spent hours with this issue. In my case it was the authorized_keys file was not UTF-8 encoded. I generated it by doing an `echo "<pubkey>" > authorized_keys` in PowerShell and the encoding was incorrect.

Added from my comments:

Yes, it was the format of the authorized_keys file. I believe VSCode allows you to see the encoding in the status bar at the bottom of the window; the old server I was on only had notepad, so I copied the text out of the file to the clipboard, created a new authorized_keys text file, and pasted the text into the new file and it fixed the issue. The issue, I guess, was that when I did an "echo ..." statement to a new file in PowerShell, it defaulted to UTF-16 text encoding.

Comment: Could you explain how you were able to change things to correct this? That info would make this a better answer. Right now, without that info, this is more of a comment.

Comment: Yes, it was the format of the `authorized_keys` file. I believe VSCode allows you to see the encoding in the status bar at the bottom of the window; the old server I was on only had notepad, so I copied the text out of the file to the clipboard, created a new authorized_keys text file, and pasted the text into the new file and it fixed the issue. The issue, I guess, was that when I did an "echo ..." statement to a new file in PowerShell, it defaulted to UTF-16 text encoding.

Comment: Add that info to your post please. Comments are temporary.